# Removing Specific Part of Function if Parameter is True

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I make the below function changes lines `$(this).html(sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i].alt.high)` and `$(this).html(sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i].alt.low)` by removing the `.alt` from both lines if `true` is passed into `simplePar`?

```
function switchTempUnitOnForecastTables(simplePar) {
for (let tableNumber = 1; tableNumber < numberOfSources+1; tableNumber++) {
        if (tableNumber == 2) {
            for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                $("#temp-high"+tableNumber+i).removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                    $(this).html(sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i].alt.high)
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
                });
                $("#temp-low"+tableNumber+i).removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                    $(this).html(sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i].alt.low)
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
                });
            }
        } else {
            for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                $("#temp-high"+tableNumber+i).removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                    $(this).html(sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i].alt.high)
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
                });
                $("#temp-low"+tableNumber+i).removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                    $(this).html(sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i].alt.low)
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
                });
            }
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a ternary expression (which is just a compact version of `if(){}...then{}`) :

```
var obj = sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i];
$(this).html(simplePar ? obj[hiLo] : obj.alt[hiLo]).removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      this expression solves your problem
```

But you can go a whole lot further and keep your code DRY by :

- using a variable as the inner loop limit (4 or 7)
- writing a generalized worker function to handle "high" vs "low"

```
function switchTempUnitOnForecastTables(simplePar) {
    // worker function
    function action(tableNumber, i, hiLo) {
        $("#temp-"+hiLo+tableNumber+i).removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
            var obj = sourcesArray[tableNumber-1].forecast[i];
            $(this).html(simplePar ? obj[hiLo] : obj.alt[hiLo]).removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
        });
    }

    for (var tableNumber = 1; tableNumber < numberOfSources+1; tableNumber++) {
        var n = (tableNumber == 2) ? 4 : 7; // inner loop limit
        for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            action(tableNumber, i, 'high');
            action(tableNumber, i, 'low');
        }
    }
}
```

As a bonus, you are no longer reliant on `let`, support for which is still somewhat basic in browsers.

Answer (score 2):

When asking a question like this, it helps to break it down to a simplified version - so it's not about your specific code. Here is one way to think about it. It can surely be more complex and check types and the number of args etc.

```
var thing = {
  name: 'Derek',
  alt: {
    name: '@sheriffderek',
  },
};

function doSomething(special) { // could be true or something else

  var outcome = undefined;

  if ( special === true ) {
    outcome = thing.alt.name;
  } else {
    outcome = thing.name;
  }

  return outcome;

}

console.log( doSomething(true) );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/gsrkm6rg/